# answer How do I redirect if a user visits the login page but is already logged in?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, session, redirect

this is session variable

```
session()->put('user_id',$id);
```

this is code from login page. I tried to redirect login page if user is already logged in or if session is already created.

```
<?PHP
session_start();
if(Session::has('YOUR_SESSION_KEY'))
{ 
return view('list');
}?>
```

but this is code is not giving any result.How can i redirect to list page if i am logged in.

Comment: If you are indeed using Laravel, I would recommend utilizing the [built-in authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication) features instead of handling it yourself. It includes many features such as automatic redirects out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

```
If ($_SESSION['user_id']) {
header('Location: yourfile.php');
}
```

header('Location: ...') is redirecting, put path to your file after Location: , Also

```
If ($_SESSION['user_id'])
```

same as

```
If (isset($_SESSION['user_id']))
```